# Change version of Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm trying to install a CMS that requires Ruby on Rails 3.2.x, which I presume means any version of Ruby on Rails that supersedes 3.2.0.

So I installed Rails version 3.2.8, but I can't use it.

Could someone explain what's going on here? Also, if a project requires 3.2.x does that mean I include it in the project's gemfile, or do I have to install it as I'm trying to do here?

[image: ruby on rails terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the version of rails you want to use, in your gemfile:

`gem 'rails', 'version'`

Change `version` to the version you want then run `$ bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

RVM is the Ruby Version Manager, not rails. If that is the only version of rails you downloaded, you can start using it. If you wanted to use a specific version of ruby, you would use that command.

To use a specific version of rails, use `rails _3.2.0_ app_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`gem list | grep rails` to check your rails versions installed.

`rvm use 1.x.x` is to switch b/w ruby versions not rails versions

Answer (score 0):

rvm is for managing ruby interpreters. With any modern rails app, just run

```
bundle install
```

In the apps directory for all the required gems to be installed (including rails). You'll need to install the bundler gem ahead of time but that's all

Answer (score 0):

`RVM` manages different `ruby` enviroment with different `gemsets`. If you want to use different `rails` version with same `ruby` you can create different `gemset` to avoid conflicts.

Assume you have two different ruby versions `1.9.3` and `2.0.0`(which are installed using `rvm`). By default it will have `default` gemset got created and uses that.

```
rvm list
```

gives:

```
=* ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ i686 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Assume you have `rails` `3.0.0` installed in default environment. And now you want to have one more `rails` version with different gemset you can create as follows:

```
  rvm gemset create rails-3.2.8
  rvm use 1.9.3-p0@rails-3.2.8  # Switching enviroment
```

This will create different environment with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8.